# How do I make the submenu appear on each menu when cursor hover?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigation, submenu

I am implementing the drop-down menu using react.js. I'm looking at the tutorial and applying it, but I've added another menu with a submenu and it doesn't work as I want. I want the submenu to appear when I put the cursor over each menu. However, when I hover over a menu, the submenu of all menus appears. 
I think there is a problem with props. But I don't know how to fix it. I would be very grateful if you could help me.

```
class Gnb extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        showAboutMenu: false
      };
    }

    handleHover = (event) => {
      this.setState({ showAboutMenu: true });
    };

    handleLeave = (event) => {
      this.setState({ showAboutMenu: false });
    };

    render() {
      return (
          <div id="menu-container">
        <nav className="nav">
          <ul className="nav__menu">
            <li>...</li>
            <li className="nav__menu-item" onMouseLeave={this.handleLeave}>
              <Link onMouseEnter={this.handleHover} className="a">
                요일별
              </Link>
              <div className="submenu-container">
                  { this.state.showAboutMenu && <Submenu_day /> }
              </div>
            </li>

            <li className="nav__menu-item" onMouseLeave={this.handleLeave}>
              <Link onMouseEnter={this.handleHover} className="a">
                장르별
              </Link>
              <div className="submenu-container">
                  { this.state.showAboutMenu && <Submenu_genre /> }
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>...</li>
          </ul>
        </nav></div>
```

this is `<Submenu_genre />`

```
const Submenu_genre =(props) =>(
  <ul className="nav__submenu">
    {genres.map((genre, index)=>(
        <li key={index} className="nav__submenu-item">
            <Link to="/" className="a">{genre.name}</Link>
        </li>
    )

    )}
</ul>
)
```

and this is a screenshot about problem

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKFqp.png)

I want only the red circle to appear...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to write new handleHover and handleLeave for the below codes

```
<div className="submenu-container">
              { this.state.showAboutMenu && <Submenu_genre /> }
          </div>
```

your showAboutMenu = true 
is the reason behind opening the submenu.

Answer (score 0):

They are both coming down because they are both referencing the same state property so:

```
 { this.state.showAboutMenu && <Submenu_genre /> }
```

And

```
 { this.state.showAboutMenu && <Submenu_day /> }
```

Are both going to be visible when 
`this.state.showAboutMenu`
is `true` regardless if they are hovered on separately.